# jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

Tags: jq

I am making an API call to AWS and getting the output in the following format :

```
{
    "ResourceTagMappingList": [
        {
            "ResourceARN": "<arn>",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "CostCenter",
                    "Value": ""
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Region",
                    "Value": "us-west-2"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Team",
                    "Value": "SRE"
                }
            ]
{
    "ResourceTagMappingList": [
        {
            "ResourceARN": "<arn>",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "CostCenter",
                    "Value": "Development"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Region",
                    "Value": "us-west-2"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Team",
                    "Value": "Architects"
                }
            ]
        }, and so on
```

and i am trying to get the entire `ResourceTagMappingList` for when `Costcenter` is untagged. and i ran the jq query for this :

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: “CostCenter”} ]}) | not)'
```

But i keep running into the following :

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: “CostCenter”} ]}) | not)                                                          
jq: 1 compile error
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[2]    exit 120   aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --tags-per-page 100 --tag-filters | 
       exit 1     jq .ResourceTagMappingList[]
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here. any help will be appreciated. Thank you. I am on Mac and using CLI version `aws-cli/2.13.25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jq` and JSON only support the ASCII double quotes, not the "smart ones".

```
... | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: “CostCenter”} ]}) | not)'
... | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select(contains({Tags: [{Key: "CostCenter"} ]}) | not)'
#                                                                   ~          ~
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you.